# Get index number of jQuery element clicked

Tags: jquery

If I write a simple selector like

```
$('.button')
```

When it's clicked, can I figure out the 'index' of that button? i.e. is it the first occurrence of `.button`, second, third?

I know I could select the third button with `$('.button')[2]` but I can't figure out how to get that 2 value.

The buttons are spread across the page, rather than being all within the same div.

Comment: i think you can use .index()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the `index()` method to do this:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  console.log(index);
});
```

The above will give you the index of the element amongst its siblings. If you want to get the index of the element within a set, for example if the `.button` elements are spread around the page and not siblings, then you can provide a selector to `index()` to match the current element within:

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index('.button');
  console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent"><button class="button">click me!</button></div>
<div class="parent"><button class="button">click me!</button></div>
<div class="parent"><button class="button">click me!</button></div>
<div class="parent"><button class="button">click me!</button></div>
<div class="parent"><button class="button">click me!</button></div>
```